# Installing Server components from Ubuntu Server 12.04.8 CD on Ubuntu Desktop 12.04

Tags: server, lamp

I have installed Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 on my system[PC] .
Now i want to install Server components like LAMP Server.
Is it possible?
Because , I'm facing some problem with my Internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can mount the cdrom to your PC. Open the terminal `CTRL` + `ALT` + `T` and write

```
sudo mount /dev/cdrom /mnt
cd /mnt
ls
```

You should see your files in the terminal. You can also open your file manager and orient to the mnt folder (it's located in the root of your hard drive /mnt, / represents root).